# VMWare ESX Server Backup with C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, vmware

Does anybody know how I can backup an VMWare ESXi server with C#.net?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you mean backing up vms, or config. Since you say the "server", I'll go with the config. Not sure how C# should enter into this, either. But, according to the [pdf](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/ESXi_management.pdf), you can use "vicfg-cfgbackup" command to back up the configuration.

Frankly, I'm working with ESX and not ESXi, but all that command-line stuff is generally how things get done. I've written automation, including some utility apps in C#, to execute SSH commands against the ESX host, and found it to be a successful approach. Most of what I've done has been more around backing up and replicating vms. This is generally a process of archiving the files to another drive (generally mounted as /backup), then push-copying to a centralized backup location on the network. From there, the backup could be picked up by another, larger system like NetBackup, etc.